Reference of the Zohar of Raayah Meheimna
Does anyone know this quote from the Zohar of Raayah Meheimna that mentions the Shem HaMeforash of Parashat Mishpatim
ועם זה ההקדמה יתבארו אלו הפסוקים באמרם מַכֵּ֥ה אִ֛ישׁ וָמֵ֖ת, שהוא משה שהרג את המצרי הנקרא איש מצרי, אם היה מזיד דינו מות יומת, האומנם כיון שתכלית כוונת משה היתה להועיל ולתקן נשמתו ע"י שיהרגהו בשם המפורש, א"כ בשוגג הרג, וזהו ואשר לא צדה זה
It is quoted verbatim in an article but without a reference number, which I personally do not know, and I wanted to ask if you know the folio number.
Shalom

It seems the reference is from משפטים ו׳
